# Using apt-get fails due to improperly configured dav_svn.conf file?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, unix, apt, dpkg

We're working on updating one of our internal development servers (running an older version of Ubuntu, 8 or 9 I'd guess), and are encountering errors when upgrading/installing packages using `apt-get`. Here's the console output of an attempt to install `zip`:

```
me@server:~$ sudo apt-get install zip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
zip is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libapache2-svn (1.5.1dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1) ...
Considering dependency dav for dav_svn:
Module dav already enabled
ERROR: Config file dav_svn.conf not properly enabled: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf is a real file, not touching it
dpkg: error processing libapache2-svn (--configure):
 subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-svn
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
me@server:~$
```

The root issue appears to be:

`ERROR: Config file dav_svn.conf not properly enabled: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf is a real file, not touching it`

The permissions of that file:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1099 2009-09-08 16:32 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf`

Google didn't turn up much, and I'm not sure how to 'properly enable' that configuration file. (Or why that would prevent `apt-get` from functioning?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out files shouldn't be stored in `mods-enabled`, they should rather be stored in `mods-available`. A symlink should then be created in `mods-enabled` pointing to the file stored in `mods-available`.

**In closing:**

First remove the original:

`mv /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf /etc/apache2/mods-available/`

Then create the symbolic link:

`ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf`

Answer (score 2):

In the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled, you should only have links to /etc/apache2/mods-available.
So, move your /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf to /etc/apache2/mods-available, do a a2enmod dav_svn, then restart your installation process.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that it may perhaps be trying to restart apache after installing libapache2-svn and when it tries to restart it can't because of a misconfiguration in dav_svn.conf. Try disabling it with the `a2dismod` command. Or just move dav_svn.conf out of the mods-enabled folder.